# In Cognos 11, how can I find all subscriptions for one email address?

Tags: cognos-11

In Cognos 1, I have been asked to change all subscriptions for one email address to another.  Since the email address is a group email address and does not have a user account in Cognos, I am unsure how to find all of the subscriptions.  Any help would be appreciated?